# Arabic doesn't display well in phonegap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

This is jQuery mobile application display some information in Arabic language but it doesn't display the Arabic language in android (eclipse, device) well, can't know the problem, what is the best solution for that?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
         <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

        <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">




            function Calc() {

                var My_killo_first = $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #ftxt').val();

                var My_killo_second = $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #stxt').val();

                var price1 = 0.075;
                var price2 = 0.145;
                var price3 = 0.16;
                var price4 = 0.24;
                var price5 = 0.34;
                var price6 = 0.6;
                var price7 = 0.74;
                var sum = 0;
                var Reset = 0;

                var My_Killo = Math.abs(My_killo_first - My_killo_second);
                Reset = My_Killo;

                if (My_Killo >= 0 && My_Killo <= 50) {


                    $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #cost').val(My_Killo * price1);
                    sum = My_Killo * price1;
                    return sum;
                }
                if (My_Killo >= 50 && My_Killo <= 100) {


                    $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #cost').val(50 * price1 + (My_Killo - 50) * price2);
                    sum = 50 * price1 + (My_Killo - 50) * price2;
                    return sum;

                }


                if (My_Killo > 0 && My_Killo <= 200) { sum = My_Killo * price3; return sum; } else { sum = 200 * price3; reset = My_Killo - 200; }
                if (My_Killo > 200 && My_Killo <= 350) { sum = sum + (reset * price4); return sum; } else { sum = sum + (150 * price4); reset = My_Killo - 350; }
                if (My_Killo > 350 && My_Killo <= 650) { sum = sum + (reset * price5); return sum; } else { sum = sum + (300 * price5); reset = My_Killo - 650; }
                if (My_Killo > 650 && My_Killo <= 1000) { sum = sum + (reset * price6); return sum; } else { sum = sum + (350 * price6); reset = My_Killo - 1000; }
                if (My_Killo > 1000) { sum = sum + (reset * price7); return sum; }
            }


            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #ftxt').val(localStorage.getItem("f"));
                $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #stxt').val(localStorage.getItem("s"));
                $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #cost').val(localStorage.getItem("c"));

                $("#go").on("click", function (event) {

                    // Prevent the usual navigation behavior
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Alter the url according to the anchor's href attribute, and
                    // store the data-foo attribute information with the url
                    $.mobile.navigate("#pageone");
                });



                $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #cost').attr("readonly", true);

                $('#calcbtn').click(function () {
                    var f = $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #ftxt').val();
                    var s = $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #stxt').val();
                    var cost = " جنيها مصري " + Calc() + " ";

                    localStorage.setItem("c", cost);
                    localStorage.setItem("f", f);
                    localStorage.setItem("s", s);
                    //localStorage.setItem("s", "Alen");
                    $('#pageone #page2main #cols #Form1 #Ul1 li #cost').val(cost);




                });


            });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

           #pageone ,#page2,#home{
          background:url(image/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;          
          -moz-background-size: cover;         
          -o-background-size: cover;          
           background-size: cover;
     }  
    </style>

    </head>
    <body lang="ar">
         <div data-role="page"  id="home" >


      <div id="page1main" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"> <h2>ط¨ط±ظ†ط§ظ…ط¬ ط­ط³ط§ط¨ ظپط§طھظˆط±ط© ط§ظ„ظƒظ‡ط±ط¨ط§ط،</h2></div>

    <div data-role="tabs">


        <ul id="two" class="tablist-content" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-theme="b"><a id="go"   >ط­ط³ط§ط¨ ظپط§طھظˆط±ط© ط§ظ„ظƒظ‡ط±ط¨ط§ط،</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
           <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"> <h2>Telemedia.com</h2></div>
          </div>
           </div>
        <div data-role="page"  id="pageone" align="center">


      <div id="page2main" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="cols" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b"  data-content-theme="c">
        <h4>ط­ط³ط§ط¨ ط§ط³طھط®ط¯ط§ظ…ظƒ ظپظٹ ط§ظ„ظƒظ‡ط±ط¨ط§ط،</h4>
             <form id="Form1">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="Ul1" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name2">ظ‚ط±ط§ط،ط© ط§ظ„ط¹ط¯ط§ط¯</label><br />
                <input type="number" name="name2" id="ftxt" value="" data-clear-btn="true"> <label for="name2">كيلو وات</label>
            </li>
             <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name2">ظ‚ط±ط§ط،ط© ظ…ط±ط¨ط¹ ط§ظ„ط­ط§ظ„ظٹط©</label><br />
                <input type="number" name="name2" id="stxt" value="" data-clear-btn="true">
            </li>
             <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name2">ط§ظ„طھظƒظ„ظپط© ط§ظ„ط§ط¬ظ…ط§ظ„ظٹط©</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="name2" id="cost" value="" data-clear-btn="false">
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <legend></legend>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><a id="calcbtn" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-theme="a">ط§ط­ط³ط¨ ط§ظ„طھظƒظ„ظپط©</a></div>
                </fieldset>
            </li>
            </ul>
          </form>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to  save the file in UTF8 Charset and what was the android version you tested on ?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Comment: how to save the file in UTF8 Charset